# Why is my custom php.ini file not loaded site wide while placed in /public_hml?

Tags: php, configuration, scope, ini, public-html

I created a custom php.ini ... it's located in /public_html.

Shouldn't it be valid and used for the whole site and directories under public_html ?

It seems not to be loaded e.g. in /public_html/cms/usr

I looked for answers on the internet or other sections of Stackoverflow but strangely did not find any answers.

Comment: If it gets picked up depends on the SAPI or FCGI wrappers. A `.user.ini` is often recognized implicitly.

Comment: Did you restart httpd?

Comment: No, it's on a shared web server. The account was switched recently to php version 5.4.13 that's what probably changed the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `php.ini` file is loaded by the PHP interpreter when it starts up. The locations searched are listed on [the PHP.net website](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php).

Comment: I've read that page. I have the following line in my .htaccess :
#SetEnv PHPRC /home/<user>/public_html/php.ini